# How to do filter for a field generated by using MAX(CASE WHEN ... END)?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have retrieved data successfully using the query below from a data in January until May generating every first and second purchase for each customer.

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN month END) AS month,
    customer_id,
    1 AS row_num,
    DATE_DIFF(MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 2 THEN verified_date END),
              MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN verified_date END), DAY) AS difference
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    customer_id;
```

Now, I would like to filter the month to get all the user doing **FIRST transaction** in Jan - Apr, and doing **SECOND transaction** anytime (Jan - May) and try this query:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 AND month IN (1,2,3,4) THEN month END) AS month,
    customer_id,
    1 AS row_num,
    DATE_DIFF(MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 2 THEN verified_date END),
              MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN verified_date END), DAY) AS difference
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    customer_id;
```

The query successfully runs, however, it generated month 1 2 3 4, and NULL in the month field.

Why there's NULL in it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's a `row_num` in `yourTable` that orders transactions of each customer chronologically, `MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 AND month IN (1,2,3,4) THEN month END) AS month,` will end up null when the row with `row_num = 1` has a month different from 1, 2, 3, or 4, i.e. "first transaction is in May".

To filter, use `HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 AND month IN (1,2,3,4) THEN month END) is not null`.